# Embedded fields in azure cognitive search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to create scoring profiles for an index in azure cognitive search. However, my datasource contains embedded fields - it included a IList called metadataList of the custom object type MetaData. How can I refer to the fields of MetaData when creating the scoring profiles?

Here's part of the class I am using to model my data:

```
[SerializePropertyNamesAsCamelCase]
public class MetaDataFileIndex
{
        [IsRetrievable(true)]
        public IList<MetaDataIndex> MetadataList { get; set; }

//Some other properties bellow
}
```

and

```
[SerializePropertyNamesAsCamelCase]
public class MetaDataIndex
{
        [IsRetrievable(true), IsSearchable]
        [Analyzer(AnalyzerName.AsString.ZhHantLucene)]
        public string PrimarySortText { get; set; }

//Some other properties bellow
}
```

Here's some of the code I used for creating the index:

```
fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<MetaDataFileIndex>();

var index = new Index()
{
    Name = name,
    Fields = fields,
    ScoringProfiles = new List<ScoringProfile>()
    {
        new ScoringProfile
        {
            Name = "fieldBooster",
            TextWeights = new TextWeights
            {
                Weights = new Dictionary<string, double>
                {
                    { "metadataList/primarySortText", [some number here] },

\\Rest of the code
```

This is giving me an error. When I use a service client to create or update the index, I receive the "request invalid error".

```
   at Microsoft.Azure.Search.IndexesOperations.<CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Search.IndexesOperationsExtensions.<CreateOrUpdateAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at
```

I believe it is because of the way I referred to the "primary sort text field" in the scoring profile, since, when I ran the same code but did not use a list of another object type in MetaDataFileIndex, it gave me no error. How can I refer to embedded fields like that?

EDIT: My Azure Cognitive Search version is 11.2.0 and it is called Azure.Search.Documents

Comment: I can't see anything immediately wrong with the scoring profile. Can you please edit your question to include the Nuget package name and version of the .NET client library for Azure Cognitive Search that you're using? Also, is there any other content in the error besides "request invalid"?

Comment: Done! And, no, that's the only error that shows up

Comment: The code you shared looks like it was written for version 10 of the SDK, which was a different package called Microsoft.Azure.Search. I don't think Azure.Search.Documents knows about attributes like [SerializePropertyNamesAsCamelCase] or [IsSearchable]. For example, the latter one was renamed. See if this article helps you to upgrade to the new SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-dotnet-sdk-migration-version-11